# Is $f$ convex function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I have a convex set $S \in \mathbb R^n$  ,  $f(x) = \inf \{|| y-x|| : y\in S\}$  is a convex function?

I don't know how I can use definition of convex function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
 f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)&=inf\{||y-(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)||:y\in S\}\\
&= inf\{||\lambda(y- x_1)+(1-\lambda)(y-x_2)||:y\in S\}\\
&\le^? inf\{\lambda||(y- x_1)||:y\in S\}+inf\{(1-\lambda)||(y-x_2)||:y\in S\}\\
&= \lambda inf\{||(y- x_1)||:y\in S\}+(1-\lambda)inf\{||(y-x_2)||:y\in S\}\\
&= \lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda)f(x_2)
\end{align}

Now you need to find an argument why this inequality with the questionmark works or doesn't work.
You will probably need that S is a convex set when thinking about this.

Comment: ,Thank you, your  way is very useful for me, if I want to proof convexity , and don't use definition, is there any theorem ?

Comment: Not that I know of